# What does the phrase "slide two fingers across the screen" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase "slide two fingers across the screen" in the following [sentence](https://mashable.com/2010/01/27/apple-ipad-gaming/):

> In N.O.V.A. you can slide three fingers over a door to open it,
>   **slide two fingers across the screen** to toss a grenade or draw a targeting box around an enemy.

Does the phrase above mean to slide anywhere on the screen? Or does it convey a particular direction? Being a non-native speaker, I cannot figure out the exact meaning the word "across" here. The Merriam-Webster defines **across** as **from one side to the other side of (something)**. Does it mean that in the given context the word "across" does not involve any particular direction, like up-down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context "across" is being used loosely to mean "along the surface of" (like a boat moving across water), not necessarily from one side to the other.

As it is written it doesn't sound like the exact start and end points really matter, nor does the direction (though presumably in the direction you want to throw the grenade).